# Select rows from a SQL Server Database table only rows that have another column as the maximum

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I'm trying to select rows from a Microsoft SQL Server Database table that for each ID in one column (ID) select only rows that have another column as the maximum (IDtoBeMaxed). For example:

From this table

```
  ID  SomeValue IDtoBeMaxed
  1   56        2  
  1   59        2  
  1   80        1
  2   55        5
  2   80        5
  2   56        3
  2   81        3
```

I only want

```
  ID  SomeValue IDtoBeMaxed
  1   56        2  
  1   59        2  
  2   55        5
  2   80        5
```

I have this query which works, but I think there should be a faster way that reduces the response time of the query. So again, this query gives me what I want, I am looking for a faster response time query.

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable 
WHERE ID = 2 
  AND IDtoBeMaxed = (SELECT MAX(IDtoBeMaxed) FROM myTable WHERE ID = 2)
```

Edits: I don't need all the rows, like I showed in the example above. I only need rows for a specific ID, just like the query that I wrote myself.

Results: I tried Shavkat query but it's not any faster than the query I had written. The rest of the answers return all the rows which I am not looking for. So this is still up for debate. But thanks for your answers so far.

Comment: The query you wrote doesn't return the values you wanted.  Are you sure this is right?  The query would never return the row with the ID of 1.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d3732/1/0

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to return all rows from the table in one query?  Something like the following would work:

```
SELECT t.Id,t.SomeValue,t.IDtoBeMaxed
FROM MyTable t
JOIN (
    SELECT Id,MAX(IDToBeMaxed) AS MaxId
    FROM MyTable
    GROUP BY Id
) AS m ON t.Id=m.Id AND t.IDToBeMaxed=m.MaxId
```

In response to your edits:

The query you've written is about as simple as you can get.  If you need to improve response time you should look at creating an index on the `ID` and `IDToBeMaxed` columns.

```
CREATE INDEX ix_IDMaxed ON MyTable(ID,IDToBeMaxed)
```

Is that an option for you?

Comment: I have to try to see if this is faster. Will let you know. Thanks.

Comment: This query is great as long as the data is JUST like that.  If you add a row it doesn't work correctly.
    INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (3, 54, 6)
Look here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d71e6/1/0

Comment: @user3083310 The sqlfiddle you posted seems to be doing the correct thing to me: returning the rows that have the largest IDToBeMaxed per ID (ID=3: IDToBeMaxed=6, ID=2: IDToBeMaxed=5, ID=1: IDToBeMaxed=2).  But Dogahe doesn't need all rows (see his edit to the question) so my query isn't exactly what he needs.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an old-school one:

```
declare @myTable table (ID int,  SomeValue int, IDtoBeMaxed int)
insert into @myTable
values
  (1,   56,        2 ), 
  (1,   59,        2 ),  
  (1,   80,        1 ),
  (2,   55,        5 ),
  (2,   80,        5 ),
  (2,   56,        3 ),
  (2,   81,        3 ),
  (3,   55,        5 ),
  (3,   80,        5 ),
  (3,   56,        5 ),
  (3,   81,        5 )

select a.*
from @myTable a left join @myTable b 
on a.ID = b.ID and a.IDtoBeMaxed < b.IDtoBeMaxed
where b.ID is null and a.ID = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

**Could you please try below...**

```
WITH    selectOne
          AS ( SELECT   ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY SomeValue, ID ORDER BY IDtoBeMaxed DESC ) AS RowNum ,
                        ID ,
                        SomeValue ,
                        IDtoBeMaxed
               FROM     myTable
             )
    SELECT  *
    FROM    selectOne
    WHERE   RowNum = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The following example return the records ranked by their IDtoBeMaxed

```
;WITH cte AS
 (SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY IDtoBeMaxed DESC) AS dr
  FROM myTable
  )
  SELECT *
  FROM cte
  WHERE dr = 1
```

Demo on [`SQLFiddle`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ab6e6/2)